# store results of looped sqlquery function

Tags: sql, r, db2

Hi I am using R and the sqlquery function, and I cannot seem to store the results of looping through the sqlquery function into a data frame.

I have:

```
year<- seq(2000,2010)

for (i in 1:length(year)){

sqlQuery(channel,paste("

select * from table where year = '",year[i],"-01-01'

",sep-""))
}
```

however doing:

```
results <- for (i in 1:length(year)){
}
```

does not store anything. athough I can store the single result of year = i by doing

```
results <- sqlQuery(channel,paste("
```

Which is obviously not what I want - I want all years. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why not just query once with the years you're interested in? `year>=2000 AND year <=2010` or something like that.

Comment: @Peyton - Because I will being doing this for around 50 different datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to answer because it's not a reproducible example, but maybe something like:

```
results <- list() 
year<- seq(2000,2010)

for (i in 1:length(year)){

results[[i]]<-sqlQuery(channel,paste("

select * from table where year = '",year[i],"-01-01'

",sep-""))
}
```

The datasets are saved in the object results, which is a list of 11 datasets. To call the first dataset with data of the year 2000, you do `results[[1]]`.

To unlist and produce the different dataframes you could do:

```
for (i in 1:length(year)){
assign(paste0("results",year[i]),results[[i]])
}
```

Dataframe `result2000` contains the data of the year 2000 and so on.

Comment: hi this works - but can this be stored into a dataframe which preserves the three columns? I will update my question to specify dataframe.

Comment: Which three columns? You perform a `select *` so all the columns are included.

Comment: yes, but select * yields multiple columns, in my case 3. I would like to store the results of the select statement in a data frame with their respective columns - or convert the list into a dataframe of 3 columns.